# Setting eigen "Transformation" class as column major for post/right multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have a function that does a lot of post/right multiplication of transformation matrixes .Now I want to convert this function to use Eigen and the problem is Eigen Transformation class does the multiplications as pre/left multiplication. Which means it has row matrix format during multiplication While storage is in column matrix format.

is there a way to change Eigen::Transformation class members from row major to column major?

Comment: Why are you saying "it has row matrix format during multiplication" and why would this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full signature for the Eigen [`Matrix`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) class is

```
Matrix<typename Scalar,
       int RowsAtCompileTime,
       int ColsAtCompileTime,
       int Options = 0,
       int MaxRowsAtCompileTime = RowsAtCompileTime,
       int MaxColsAtCompileTime = ColsAtCompileTime>
```

The 4th argument `Options` is [described as](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html)

> Options is a bit field. Here, we discuss only one bit: `RowMajor`. **It specifies that the matrices of this type use row-major storage order**; by default, the storage order is column-major. See the page on storage orders. For example, this type means row-major 3x3 matrices

So you could say, for example,

```
Matrix<int, 3, 4, ColMajor> foo;    // column major
Matrix<int, 4, 3, RowMajor> bar;    // row major
```

[More documentation on Storage Orders](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html)

If the transformation you are referring to is [`Eigen::Transform`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html) this also has an `Options` template argument, which you can also pass `RowMajor` vs `ColMajor`. Any matrices it produces will follow the same convention that you specify.

```
Transform<typename Scalar,
          int Dim,
          int Mode,
          int _Options = AutoAlign>
```

Again the `_Options` argument is described as

> `_Options` has the same meaning as in class `Matrix`. It allows to specify `DontAlign` and/or `RowMajor`. **These `Options` are passed directly to the underlying matrix type**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately We dont have the chance to change how the actual matrix is constructed in transformation class. In this case what do you recommend?

Comment: If you could edit your answer for Eigen::Transform as I specifically asked for it, I would be glad to mark your answer as true.